# How to replace (or append) certain terms in string with enumerated alphabet letters?

Tags: python-3.x, replace, enumerate

I would like to the replace (or append) instances of a term in a string, with where they appear in the string with letters in alphabetical order.

I have the code:

```
message = "This <*> is <*> a <*> message"
```

I want it to print like:

```
This <*.A> is <*.B> a <*.C> message
```

I have been able to add a number to each of the terms in the message but that is the extent of it. Can someone please show me what I need to do to get the output?

Comment: Here's a decent resource for learning python formatting: https://pyformat.info/

Answer (score 0):

you could use

Traditional way:

```
def replace(message):
    message_list = message.split()
    indexes = [index for index, element in enumerate(message_list) if element == '<*>']
    alphabets = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'[:len(indexes)]
    for index, alphabet in zip(indexes, alphabets):
        message_list[index] = '<*.' + alphabet + '>'
    return ' '.join(message_list)
```

or use regular expressions

```
import re

def replace(message):
     range = len(re.findall('\<\*\>', message))
     for alphabet in 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'[:range]:
          replace_with = '<*.' + alphabet + '>'
          message = re.sub('\<\*\>', replace_with, message, 1)
     return message
```